# How to convert angular web application to ionic hybrid mobile application

Tags: angular, angularjs, ionic-framework, native, ionic-native

HI i am having a problem so i am an angular developer and i developed a web application using angular as the front end javascript framework and in the back end i have .net core as the api now i want to convert my angular application to a hybrd mobile application using ionic i searched a lot but couldn’t find some complete tutorial if some one can be kind enough and give me a detailed procedure on how i can do this itll be very help full any information you need would be provided any kind of help would be appreciated, thankyou!!

i scattered through forums and found one way is to
create a new ionic app using type=angular
copy contents of angular app to src/app in ionic
add adriod as platform
build the app
done this but this throws so many unwanted unusual never seen before errors

1. i just want if possible a detailed process of how to convert it along with some side notes of things i might have to do also a little hint on routing the application

Comment: You don't need ionic, ionic is a framework that gives you a UI for mobile with iOS/Android style. What you need is capacitor to convert your web app into a mobile app : https://capacitorjs.com/docs/getting-started